# Register type with default value in parameter

Tags: c#, ioc-container, autofac

I have type with default value in constructor :

> public Receiver(ISerializer serializer, string key, IInterceptor
>   interceptor = default(IInterceptor))

I try to register this type :

```
       containerBuilder
            .RegisterType<Receiver>()
            .Named<IReceiver>("receiver")
            .UsingConstructor(new[] { typeof(ISerializer), typeof(string)})
            .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
             {
                   ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ISerializer>("stringSerializer"),
                   new NamedParameter("key", "noneKey")
             });
```

And I get the following exception :

> No matching constructor exists on type
>   'Channels.Receiver'.

Can you help me on how to register a type with a default value in a constructor ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default parameter is inserted by the C# compiler at call sites where `Receiver` is being constructed.

However this is not used by `autofac` when resolving the constructor.

Therefore you will have to add it as a parameter explicitly:

```
builder
    .RegisterType<Receiver>()
    .Named<IReceiver>("receiver")
    .UsingConstructor(new[] { typeof(ISerializer), typeof(string), typeof(IInterceptor) })
    .WithParameters(new List<Parameter>
    {
        ResolvedParameter.ForNamed<ISerializer>("stringSerializer"),
        new NamedParameter("key", "noneKey"),
        new NamedParameter("interceptor", null)
    });
```